# $L_p$ space, convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $1\le p<\infty$ and $f\in L_p(\mathbb{R})$. How to prove that $$\lim_{\lambda\to 1}\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}\big|f(\lambda x)-f(x)\big|^p\, dx=0.$$
Is it true for arbitrary measure spaces?

Comment: Do you consider $\lambda > 1 $?

Comment: What does $f(\lambda x)$ even mean for an arbitrary measure space?

Comment: I mean other measure on $\mathbb R$

Answer (score 2):

As a hint for the proof on $\mathbb{R}^n$, use the fact that $C_C \subseteq L^p$ is dense; that is, any $L^p$ function can be approximated in the $L^p$ norm via a continuous function supported on a compact set. Then say something about uniform continuity.

---

The claim is *not* true for arbitrary measure spaces: In particular, it's false for the counting measure. Choose $f(x) = 1$ at $x = 1$, and $0$ otherwise.